# How can I get an accurate relative yaw angle from a 6DOF IMU like the LSM6DS3 with minimal gyro drift?

Tags: accelerometer, robotics, gyroscope, kalman-filter, imu

I currently have a platform that has a 6DOF IMU (the LSM6DS3) with no magnetometer. I want to get as accurate of a relative yaw angle reading as possible, avoiding or minimizing any gyro drift. I tried a simple approach of:

a) calculate the gyro angular rate zero-offset by computing the average gyro angular rate reading for a few seconds while my platform is known to be stationary.

b) read the angular rate while the LSM6DS3 reports a new reading is available (so, this should essentially be the output data rate I configured, i.e. 416Hz). I subtract this from the zero-offset calculated in (a) above to get the degrees/s angular rate and then integrate (multiply the time delta with the degrees/s angular rate and add to the current yaw angle).

Is this the best I can do to avoid gyro drift issues if I want to get as accurate of a relative yaw rating possible?

I looked a little bit at Kalman filters and Madgwick filters and Mahony filters but they don't seem to suggest the ability to improve yaw angle readings as it seems the accelerometer would not be useful to calculate the yaw angle? Is that correct?